# How can I increment the numerical value in my WHERE clause using a loop?

Tags: postgresql, loops, plpgsql, control-flow

I am currently using the **UNION ALL** workaround below to calculate **old_eps_tfq** regression slopes of each **ticker** based off its corresponding **rownum** value (see `WHERE rownum < x`). I am interested to know what the **old_eps_tfq** is when `rownum < 4` then increment **4** by **1** to find out what **old_eps_tfq** is when `rownum < 5`, and so on (there are ~20 rownum)

Could I use PL/pgSQL for this?

```
SELECT * FROM(
    WITH regression_slope AS(
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ticker ORDER BY earnings_growths_ped) AS rownum,
            *
        FROM "ANALYTICS"."vEARNINGS_GROWTHS"
        --WHERE ticker = 'ACN' 
        ORDER BY ticker )   
    SELECT
        ticker,
        current_period_end_date,
        max(earnings_growths_ped) AS max_earnings_growths_ped, 
        --max(rownum) AS max_rownum, 
        round(regr_slope(old_eps_tfq, rownum)::numeric, 2) AS slope,
        round(regr_intercept(old_eps_tfq, rownum)::numeric, 2) AS y_intercept,
        round(regr_r2(old_eps_tfq, rownum)::numeric, 3) AS r_squared
    FROM regression_slope  
    WHERE rownum < 4
    GROUP BY ticker, current_period_end_date
    ORDER BY ticker asc ) q

UNION ALL 

SELECT * FROM(
    WITH regression_slope AS(
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ticker ORDER BY earnings_growths_ped) AS rownum,
            *
        FROM "ANALYTICS"."vEARNINGS_GROWTHS"
        --WHERE ticker = 'ACN' 
        ORDER BY ticker )   
    SELECT
        ticker,
        current_period_end_date,
        max(earnings_growths_ped) AS max_earnings_growths_ped, 
        --max(rownum) AS max_rownum, 
        round(regr_slope(old_eps_tfq, rownum)::numeric, 2) AS slope,
        round(regr_intercept(old_eps_tfq, rownum)::numeric, 2) AS y_intercept,
        round(regr_r2(old_eps_tfq, rownum)::numeric, 3) AS r_squared
    FROM regression_slope  
    WHERE rownum < 5
    GROUP BY ticker, current_period_end_date
    ORDER BY ticker asc ) q
```

[Here is my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrI7c.png)

Comment: PLease insert your data sample as plain text in your question, not as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top query `SELECT * FROM (...) q` sounds like useless.
Then you can try this :

```
WITH regression_slope AS(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ticker ORDER BY earnings_growths_ped) AS rownum,
        *
    FROM "ANALYTICS"."vEARNINGS_GROWTHS"
    --WHERE ticker = 'ACN' 
    ORDER BY ticker )   
SELECT
    max,
    ticker,
    current_period_end_date,
    max(earnings_growths_ped) AS max_earnings_growths_ped, 
    --max(rownum) AS max_rownum, 
    round(regr_slope(old_eps_tfq, rownum)::numeric, 2) AS slope,
    round(regr_intercept(old_eps_tfq, rownum)::numeric, 2) AS y_intercept,
    round(regr_r2(old_eps_tfq, rownum)::numeric, 3) AS r_squared
FROM regression_slope
INNER JOIN generate_series(4, 24) AS max -- the range 4 to 24 can be adjusted to the need
   ON rownum < max
GROUP BY max, ticker, current_period_end_date
ORDER BY max asc, ticker asc
```